# Load different files depends of environment

Tags: node.js, koa

I have an application in KOA (framework of node js), my index load a configuration file and I would like load other different file when I check the application with my tests. 
How can I load different files in function of the environment?

Answer (score 3):

You can define an environment variable.

You can use `process.env.NODE_ENV`or a custom one such as `process.env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE`

For example you can launch your KOA server for test with

```
NODE_ENV=test node index.js
```

Then load your config file :

```
const config = require(`${process.env.NODE_ENV}`.json);
```